# why can I require 'active_support/core_ext'?

Tags: ruby, require

In a non-rails project, I can just install `activesupport` standalone. When I need its cool monkeypatch features:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```

But how does it work? Does it automatically require all files in [active_support/core_ext](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/20768176292cbcb883ab152b4aa9ed8c664771cd/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext)? How `Ruby` know they are here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the file [named `core_ext.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/20768176292cbcb883ab152b4aa9ed8c664771cd/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb).

But no `require` can't load directories.

Answer (score 3):

This is how (example for my platform):

```
> gem which active_support
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.12/lib/active_support.rb
> cd /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.12/lib/active_support
> cat core_ext.rb
```

```
filenames = Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/core_ext/*.rb"].sort.map do |path|
  File.basename(path, '.rb')
end

filenames.each { |filename| require "active_support/core_ext/#{filename}" }
```

So you see that `core_ext.rb` is the file that will "autoload" every `*.rb` file in the `core_ext` directory.